# php with links to other php files

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Here is my "index.php" page:

```
<?php

if($_GET['p']==4)
$p='dodaj.php';
if($_GET['p']==3)
$p='dodaj_wplate.php';
else if($_GET['p']==2)
$p='dodaj_u.php';
else
$p='index.php';
?>

Wybierz coś!.<br>
<a href="index.php?p=4">Dodaj osobę</a><br>
<a href="index.php?p=3">Dodaj wpłatę</a><br>
<a href="index.php?p=2">lDodaj ubezpieczenie</a><br>

<?

include $p;

?>
```

And I am getting error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\index.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\index.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\index.php on line 7
Wybierz co!.
Dodaj osobę
Dodaj wpłatę
lDodaj ubezpieczenie
```

How can I define my "p"? Because I can see there is problem.

Also, not related to question, can you give me any link to layout tutorial related to php?

Comment: `$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'some_default_value';`, and use `$page` later on. Also, a `switch` may be better then a lot of `else if`s.

Comment: Next to what @Wrikken (rightly) wrote, you probably just only want to have an array that is mapping a number to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
Wybierz cos!.<br>
<a href="<?php echo((isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']==4) ? 'dodaj.php' : 'index.php?p=4');?>">Dodaj osobe</a><br>
<a href="<?php echo((isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']==3) ? 'dodaj_wplate.php' : 'index.php?p=3');?>">Dodaj wplate</a><br>
<a href="<?php echo((isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']==2) ? 'dodaj_u.php' : 'index.php?p=2');?>">lDodaj ubezpieczenie</a>
```

Comment: Cool, worked, but why it does not continue to page "dodaj.php" for example?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: When I click on link "Dodaj osobe" for example. I want the link to put me on site 'dodaj.php', not index.php?p=4. When I press any link I am on the site with all 3 links.

Comment: well, I will update my answer

Comment: Now it works, but I gotta double click it. This is kind of disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$p = 'index.php';
if( isset($_GET['p']) ){

    switch( $_GET['p'] ){

        case '2':
            $p = 'dodaj_u.php';
        break;

        case '3':
            $p = 'dodaj_wplate.php';
        break;

        case '4':
            $p = 'dodaj.php';
        break;

    }

}

?>

Wybierz coś!.<br>
<a href="index.php?p=4">Dodaj osobę</a><br>
<a href="index.php?p=3">Dodaj wpłatę</a><br>
<a href="index.php?p=2">lDodaj ubezpieczenie</a><br>

<?

include $p;

?>
```